# Does a C++ object have a fixed size?

Tags: c++, class, object, size

I used to C's fixed size of structure.
Don't know if a C++ object is fixed or not. I mean is it always possible to predict what size is for an object? during compiling time? and/or run time? or impossible unless using sizeof operator?
I knew it's hardware platform dependent. Beside that, what else?

Comment: The layout of an object depends on the ABI, which is platform specific. An example is http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A C++ object has a fixed size, of course. If it wasn't fixed, and you made an array of objects, how would the compiler know how much space to allocate?

The same rules that apply to structs apply here, the total from each type of data's size plus any padding for alignment and if you use any virtual functions that's an extra 4 or 8 bytes for the V table pointer depending on the architecture of your machine.

Comment: If this is totally true, then it is exactly I wanted. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: It's wrong. `new int[x]` is the counter-example. Arrays are a single object, even variable-length arrays like this. "How would the compiler know how much space to allocate for an array of these?" is not a refutation: There are no arrays of variable-length arrays.

Comment: It`s correct. If `new int[x]` is used then obviously you need a pointer that points to the dynamically allocated ints on the heap. This pointer size will vary slightly according to architecture. Of course this allocated data is separate from the actual class or struct size.

so
    `class Foo
    {
      int someInt;
      int* someInts;
    }
`
Will always be 8 bytes if on a 32 bit system where ints are also 4 bytes in size. If, in the constructor, you had `someints = new int[6400]` and called `sizeof()` on this instance of `Foo` it will still be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The size of the object itself can be retrieved by calling `sizeof` and is known at compile time. But the object could manage some other resource, and there is no direct way of knowing how much memory that resource takes.

For example, gcc 32bits, `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is 12 (3 pointers), but it might be managing a few million instances of `T` that might be large itself.

Comment: Containers such as `std::string` `std::map` all store data on the heap, so their size is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Even with C you're at the mercy of padding, alignment etc. That being said, the size of a `struct`/`class` in C++ is generally predictable if you know the sizes of the member variables. The only time that this becomes a bit murky is when you start introducing `virtual functions` and `virtual inheritance`. In that case the compiler needs to store some extra bookkeeping information. Regardless, the size of each object is known at compile time, and thus the `sizeof` operator is a compile-time feature (which explains why it can be used for template meta-programming.)

C++ follows the "don't pay for what you don't use" principle. If all you're doing is grouping together similar data and functions into a class, your objects will behave the same as if they were structs in C with global functions. If you need more advanced features, then you pay for them per use.

Comment: Do you mean each virtual function use would create one more items, which may have pointers and other system/application variables/pointers? Does it mean after the use of a virtual function, you use the operator sizeof will see the difference?
How about another object within this object? 
What size is for a function? a size of function pointer?

Comment: The object will need to store a pointer to a table of function pointers (called the virtual function table, or vtable.) Where it actually stores this pointer within the struct is implementation defined however, which can screw with any notion you have of object layout.

Answer (score 2):

Any type has a well known size, point.  (Dynamic memory allocation does not account)

A declaration using a forward declaration of a type, only, is invalid:

```
class Unknown;
class Failure {
   Unknown x;
};
```

Using a pointer makes the declaration valid:

```
class Unknown;
class Success {
   Unknown *x;
};
```

Actually C and C++ do not differ. Both require a well known size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No! `class` or `struct` may allocate arbitrary size for their interned data from heap. The members to manage this will setup a fixed size structure though.